# Does this $a$ exists and how to calculate it if it exists?

Tags: limits

I was trying to solve some problem from a question here on MSE by first trying to find something about simplified version, and, if I calculated correctly I obtained:

> $$\lim_{n \to + \infty} (\sqrt{a})^{3^n} \cdot \prod_{k=2}^{n} (\dfrac {a}{k})^{3^{n-k+1}}=1$$

Even if my calculations are not right this is interesting in itself and what I would like to know is does such an $a$ exists? That is, even though I obtained this result and am trying to find closed form for $a$ (or an approximation) I really do not know even if there exists an $a$ that would satisfy this limit problem.

> Does it exists? How to calculate it if it exists?

Comment: Could you please link the question from "here on MSE"?  How can we tell if you calculated correctly to obtain the formula you ask about, without knowing the original question?

Comment: Just looking I would expect the limit to be $0$.  Once $n$ gets huge compared to $a$ most of those $\frac ak$ terms will be tiny and overwhelm the $a^{3^n/2}$

Comment: @RossMillikan This is $+ \infty \cdot 0$ limit, It could be that such an $a$ exists.

Comment: @Shalom:  I am suggesting that the $0$ is much stronger than the $+\infty$.  I am not certain.

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand what you´re saying, but I believe that there is such an $a$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $a \gt 1$ the limit is $0$, not $1$.

Lets start with the numerator of the product.
$$\prod_{k=2}^na^{3^{n-k+1}}=a^{\sum_{k=2}^n3^{n-k+1}}\\
\sum_{k=2}^n3^{n-k+1}=\frac{3^n-3^1}{3-1}\approx \frac {3^n}2
\\ \text {and all the } a\text{s  including the leading factor give us }a^{3^n} $$
We will loosely bound the denominator from below, remembering that $n \gg a$
$$\prod_{k=2}^nk^{3^{n-k+1}}\gt \prod_{k=a^3}^nk^{3^{n-k+1}}\gt \prod_{k=a^3}^n(a^3)^{3^{n-k+1}}=(a^3)^{\frac{3^n-3^{a^3}}{3-1}}=a^{\frac 323^n}\cdot a^{-3^{a^3}}$$
The trailing $a^{-3^{a^3}}$ is just a constant.  For any $a \gt 1$ the terms depending on $n$ will be less than $a^{\frac 123^n}$, which can be made as small as we want.